# can't access component from Super user in joomla 2.5

Tags: components, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have made changes in User permission Joomla 2.5 akeeba Component. because i have added some users under Super User. I have Blocked permission to access Administrator access for other users. At that all things worked correctly. After few days I changed version of akeeba backup. After that I can't access to the component  from **Super User** too.. I have  uninstall the component and again Installed it. But the same problem

> 403 - An error has occurred. Access forbidden

How to resolve this error.. what are the changes to be in the DB or anything!!

Comment: Have you checked the forum on the Akeeba website? If there is no information about it, you might want to contact Nicholas the developer as it might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a 403 Error, then it seems to me a problem with the file or directory permissions on your webspace - not within joomla. Joomla does not show a 403 error if you are not allowed to access a function due to your joomla access level.